# How to select specific Google Calendar through Google API

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-data-api

How to select non-primary calendar using Google's Calendar API? I can see from documentation you can get full list of calendards, but nothing about how to select specific one.

For example I have calendar with title 'My Calendar_1'

I don't want to iterate over all calendars to check each name.

Seems to be it should some how use Query, but the documentation on its application is so poor.

Thanks in advance.